# {TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'} with input

Tags: python, input, sum, grok

I am new to python and I was learning with Grok, but I got stuck on this part

```
money = input("Enter the expenses: ")
addup = money.split()
total = sum(addup)
print("Total: ", total)
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Yeah.. we're going to need the line number you get the error on - is it the sum() function ? Are you trying to add a string to an integer?

Comment: @Oscar I have edited my answer according to your problem.I f you find the answer helpful mark it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to "sum" strings, which of course doesn't work. You'll need to make them integers or floats to add them up. How exactly you could do that depends on what you expect the user to input.

This may work

```
addup=[float(x) for x in addup]
```

Comment: Down vote and no explanation? Not very helpful of you.

Comment: it's just a variable that gets used in the list comprehension. Oscar made addup a list when he uses split.

Comment: it is a variable used for iterating.

Comment: @OscarLam This is a list comprehension. It works like any other `for` loop.  Read more: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

```
money=map(float,input().split()) #could have use int as well if input was a sequence of integers
total=sum(money)
print("Total:",total)
```

You could also do this:

```
    Total=sum(map(float,input().split())) #could have use int as well if input was a sequence of integers
    print("Total:",total)
```

In python input is default taken as a string you need to typecast it

```
int(input("enter the expenses should work: "))
```

or if it is float

```
float(input("enter the expenses should work: "))
```

in general all you need is  to typecast or if your input is a list of numbers do

```
map(int,input().split()) #can use float here as well
```

In python 2.x map will create a list and in python 3.x it will create generator.

Comment: what if they're floats eh?

Comment: I suspect the intended input is something like `12 34 56 78` all at once